# import function Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new at Java. We got a Test code for classes and now I am trying to add them to Eclipse. but somehow its not working whenever I wanna do "import vehicle" to the main program.

Can someone please help me how I should do this?

```
import vehicle;
class MainProgram
{
public static int main()
{
vehicle bicycle= new vehicle("BMX", 2, "4.5 Bar");
vehicle car = new vehicle("VW", 4, "1.9 Bar");

.
. 

class vehicle
{
//Instance variables:
private String name;
private int tyrenumbers;
private String tyrestyle;
private boolean drive;
```

Comment: 1) Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, so it should be `Vehicle`. --- 2) If `Vehicle.java` and `MainProgram.java` are in the same folder (package), then you don't need to import it. Since they both seem to be in the *unnamed* package, you can't import it. Just use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand your problem but, you should create a new class for vehicle
then, in the main program class import the vehicle package.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a constructor for your vehicle class that takes the three arguments. Add the following bit of code into your vehicle class:

```
public vehicle(String name, int tyrenumbers, String tyrestyle) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tyrenumbers = tyrenumbers;
    this.tyrestyle = tyrestyle;
}
```

Look through the constructor related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%2bconstructor?tab=Votes) to learn more

Comment: https://hasteb.in/joturexe.java that's the whole code , i just wanna get it to run in eclipse :-D

Comment: https://hasteb.in/zucisequ.java is valid java code but it's hard to help without knowing the intent of your code